# Create a binding handler for addclass

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, knockout.js

how can I create a binding handler that will addclass to a div

```
<div class="control-group" id ="nameControlGroup">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value:scheduleClause">
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="control-group">                 
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind = "click:addScheduleClause">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need a bindinghandler so that everytime I click the button it will add a class to nameControlGroup div

Answer (score 1):

You should create a CssClass observable property in your ViewModel, and update it in addScheduleClause method:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.CssClass = ko.observable();

    self.addScheduleClause = function() {
       self.CssClass("CSS CLASS");
    }
}
```

In html part you should add binding for div nameControlGroup:

```
<div class="control-group" id ="nameControlGroup" data-bind="css: CssClass">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn').addEventListener("click",function(){

    document.getElementById('nameControlGroup').setAttribute("class", "your_class_to_add");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use this button for it:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind = "click:addScheduleClause">Save</button>
```

Then in your "addScheduleClause" function just add one line of code into it

```
$('#nameControlGroup').addClass('newClassName');
```

I don't think making a binding handler for this is such a good idea. But if you insist (something like this should work):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myspecialbutton = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor){
    $(element).on('change', function(event){
      $('#nameControlGroup').addClass('newClassName');
    });
  }
};
```

Or even better, what Alexander wrote.

Answer (score -1):

This should work as jQuery solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('button').click(function(){
        jQuery('#nameControlGroup').addClass('YOUR CLASS NAME');
     });
});
```